# copy/update records of certain columns of one row to all other rows of the same table based on ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-update, record

I have a MSSQL 2012 table where only the **first row** of a certain sheetname column contains values for **customer**, **project** and **plant**, based on an ID.

Now I want to "**copy**" the records of those three columns **to all other rows** where the ID is the same and sheetname =  "sheet 1".

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed717/1) with an *input* and desired *output* table.

With "copy" I mean I don't want to update the actual table, instead I want to create a view that will only **populate** the columns with those records.

At the moment I have no idea how I can get there so hopefully you can help me out. 
I doubt I get a great performance with a view. A procedure will do a better job I guess.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I've updated the fiddle with another task: I added a comment column that if the record is null the previous comment value should be used.

Comment: you can't determine which row is the newest without a unique ID or a timestamp. You can give them a row number but that is no guarantee

Answer (score 1):

first of all you did put the same id for all the row in your input table, i assumed that was an error. And then i confess i did not exactly get your explication, i think you suffer mostly from a bad design, no primary key, and only one table when you could easily break your table into two different one. 
But there is my humble solution, again not sure it really do what you want but he could help you to do it.

```
SELECT 
myInputTable.id,
myInputTable.row,
j.customer,j.project,
j.plant,myInputTable.sheetname
FROM myInputTable
LEFT JOIN myInputTable AS j
ON (myInputTable.id=j.id AND j.customer IS NOT NULL)
```

The Join allows you to add column in the result from a table
with the left join you will have at least one row for each row of myInputTable, 
with the condition after the on, you say you want to add a row of j only if the id is the same AND if there is a customer name.

Comment: thanks for the stmt! Do you have an idea for my updated requirement?

Comment: If you can add a column to your table you can surely use a better design, it's the best advice, your design is wrong on so many levels.Then i would say if you don't have any key on your table there is no way to be sure your rows will stay in the same order, so no way to know which row is the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is flawed. Look at the high number of null values and normalise these values out. After another quick look Customer, Project and Plant can be normalised to other tables - joining these together will give you output 2.

Comment: I know the design is wrong - but I can't do anything about it. So I need some workaround.

Comment: this is not an answer. This is a comment

Comment: @t-clausen.dk how so ? the answer is to redesign.

Answer (score 0):

if all the other columns are always null, you can use this view like this with good performance:

```
CREATE VIEW v_yourview as
SELECT id, row, min(customer) over (partition by id) customer,
min(project) over (partition by id) project,
min(plant) over (partition by id) plant,
sheetname
from myInputTable
```

If you want to update all rows. Since there are no timestamp nor Unique ID in your data, I faked it by adding a temporary row_number:
(I believe you made an error in your fiddle, I tried to correct it)

```
CREATE TABLE  #myInputTable 
    (
     id int, 
     row int, 
     customer varchar(30),
      project varchar(30),
      plant varchar(30),
      sheetname varchar(30),
      comment varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO #myInputTable
(id, row, customer,project,plant, sheetname,comment)
VALUES
(1,1, 'Customer Name', 'Project Name', 'Plant Name', 'sheet 1','comment 1')
,
(1,1,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 2',Null)
,(1,1,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 3',Null)
,(1,2,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 2','comment 2')
,(1,2,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 3',Null)
-- I changed value for ID from 1 to 2 in next line
,(2,1, 'Customer Name 2', 'Project Name', 'Plant Name', 'sheet 1', 'new comment')
,
(2,1,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 2',Null)
,(2,1,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 3',Null)
,(2,2,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 2',Null)
,(2,2,NULL ,NULL ,NULL , 'sheet 3',Null)


;with t1 as
(
select *, row_number() over (order by id) rn
from #myInputTable
)
update t1
set 
customer = t2.customer,
project  = t2.project,
plant    = t2.plant,
comment  = t3.comment
from t1
join #myInputTable t2
on t2.customer is not null
and t1.id = t2.id
cross apply(select top 1 comment from t1 t where rn <= t1.rn and comment is not null order by rn desc) t3
where t1.customer is null

select * from #myInputTable
```